# Matrix derivative

Tags: matrix, matrix-equations

I am looking to compute the derivative of the following expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\mathrm{tr}\left[A\exp(X)\right]$$
where $A$ is both a symmetrical and positive-definite matrix and $X$ is a symmetrical matrix. As a result, $\exp(X)$ is symmetrical and definite-positive.

Just as a reminder, the matrix exponential $\exp(X)$ is defined as:
$$\exp(X)=I+X+\frac12X^2+\dots$$
so if we diagonalize it ($X=UDU^T$), then we have that $\exp(X)=U\exp(D)U^T$.

I have been looking at this for hours and I am unable to calculate a simple solution as soon as the matrix is not a trivial $1\times1$ matrix.

** Edit **

There are a few answers and hints that relate to $\mathrm{tr}(A^TB)=\sum A\odot B$, but this doesn't work in general for non-linear function, as far as I understand. For example:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\mathrm{tr}\left[A^TX^2\right]=AX^T+X^TA$$
for generic square matrices $A$ and $X$. As these two matrices do not commute in general, we can't simplify the expression.

** Edit 2 **

I actually found that the expression is fairly more complicated than I expected. Part of the answer is described here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/403404/468380

** Final edit **

I believe that the answer from Lutz Lehmann is the closest to what it is possible to do given my original question. Basically, this is a very challenging problem, with no closed form solution. Fortunately, I was able to rewrite my original problem using matrix logarithms and in this case, I do get a commuting derivative which simplifies greatly the work.

Comment: The trace of the matrix product $tr(A^TB) = A ⊙ B$, so don't worry about $A$. The trace is additive in the sense that $tr(I+X + \frac{1}{2} X^2 ...) = tr(I) + tr(X) + \frac{1}{2}tr(X^2)...$. I suggest you start by deriving $\frac{∂}{∂X} tr(X^k) = k X^{k-1}$.

Comment: @CharlieS, is $\odot$ the Frobenius inner product?

Comment: Whatever the sum of the coefficientwise product is called. Sometimes its the "double dot". I've seen like 10 names for it. $tr(A^T B) = \sum A_{ij} B_{ij}$

Comment: Is $Ae^X$ supposed to just represent the regular product of matrix $A$ and matrix $e^X$?

Comment: In any case, both the trace and multiplication with $A$ are linear operations, so applying the chain rule shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Yes, this is simply the matrix product of $A$ and $\exp(X)$, which can be defined as the Taylor expansion in the question.

Comment: @CharlieS: But that does not work directly that way for the derivative of $Tr(AX^n)$. The directional derivative in direction $H$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n Tr(AX^{k-1}HX^{n-k})=\sum_{k=1}^n Tr(X^{n-k}AX^{k-1}H)$, so extracting the derivative gives $\sum_{k=1}^n X^{n-k}AX^{k-1}$

Comment: @LutzLehmann That is exactly the problem I have, the matrices $A$ and $X$ do not commute in general so the expression doesn't simplify.

Comment: $tr(A^TB)=\Sigma A⊙B$ is valid even if $B = exp(X)$, but I see now that this property isn't particularly useful. Unless you know $\frac{∂}{∂X}exp(X)$, which looks pretty nasty

Comment: OP: please consider writing an answer to your own question to detail the solution that you have found.

Comment: SIde note: the derivative of the matrix exponential is described in more detail in Higham's book *Functions of matrices*.

Comment: See also the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) for the treatment of $\exp(-X)\exp(X+tH)=\exp(t·…+O(t^2)=I+t·…+O(t^2)$ for the computation of the directional derivative. A similar case is discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503844/derivative-of-matrix-exponential-of-linear-combination. Study especially the relation to the adjoint and the infinitesimal variant.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, will do, it's actually fairly more complicated than I first expected when I posted. There are several ways to look at this, some involving approximations seem much simpler to implement than the actual exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the very helpful wikipedia page [*"derivative of the exponential map"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map), based around the [*"Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), the relevant formula for a directional derivative is
$\newcommand{\ad}{\operatorname{ad}}$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}e^{X+tH}\Big|_{t=0}=e^X\phi_1(-\ad_X)[H]
$$
where $\phi_1(z)=\frac{e^z-1}z=1+\frac{z}2+\frac{z^2}{3!}+…+\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}+…$ and $\ad_X[Y]=[X,Y]$, so that $(\ad_X)^2[Y]=[X,[X,Y]]$ etc.

Now including the trace we get
$$
\newcommand{\Tr}{\operatorname{Tr}}
\Tr(A·[X,Y])=\Tr(AXY-AYX)=-\Tr([X,A]·Y)
\\
\Tr(A·[X,[X,Y]])=-\Tr([X,A]·[X,Y])=\Tr([X,[X,A]]·Y)
\\
\Tr(Ae^X·\phi_1(-\ad_X)[H])=\Tr(\phi_1(+\ad_X)[Ae^X]·Y)
$$

So that finally, how helpful it may ever be,
$$
\frac{\partial \Tr(Ae^X)}{\partial X}=\phi_1(\ad_X)[Ae^X]
$$

---

I like the derivation where some very large $N$ is picked and $\exp(X)$ approximated as $(I+\frac{X}{N})^N+O(N^{-2})$. Then
\begin{align}
\exp(X+tH)&=\left(I+\frac{X}{N}+t\frac{H}{N}\right)^N+O(N^{-2})
\\
&=\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)^N
+t\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)^{N-k}\frac{H}{N}\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)^{k-1}
+O(N^{-2},t^2)
\end{align}

The term linear in $t$ now is approximately equal to
$$
\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)^N·\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\left(I-\frac{X}{N}\right)^kH\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)^{k}
\\
=\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)^N·\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}
\left(I-\frac{\ad_X}{N}\right)^kH+O(N^{-2})
$$
with $\left(I-\frac{X}{N}\right)H\left(I+\frac{X}{N}\right)=H-\frac{[X,H]}N+O(N^{-2})$. This expression can be further approximately recognized as Riemann sum for the integral
$$
e^X·\int_0^1\exp(-s\ad_X)[H]\,ds=e^X·\phi_1(-\ad_X)[H]
$$
as claimed, as the integration now proceeds completely in the commutative operator algebra generated by $\ad_X$.

Comment: This is indeed what I think is the correct approach in general. That being said, it's problematic as it involves an infinite sum that's not straightforward to compute numerically. I will check but I think that I can rewrite the problem as a perturbative one, so I can truncate the sum early (and it becomes tractable).

Comment: I'm really not sure how helpful that eventually is. $\phi_1(M)$ can be evaluated with the same efficiency as $\exp(M)$, but notice that if $X$ is $n\times n$, then $ad_X$ acts on its argument  as vector, that is, in a suitable basis $ad_X$ is a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.

Comment: This gets very complicated to compute in practice, I went back to my original problem and reformulated it as a matrix logarithm. In this form, I get something like $[\log(X),I]=0$ so it's much more tractable.

Answer (score 3):

Observing that both the trace and the multiplication with a matrix $A$ are linear operations, it is easy to apply the chain rule. For this, first see that
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}  [\text{tr} X ]
  =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \left[\sum_{l} X_{ll}\right]
  = \delta_{ij}.
$$
From there, you can get the rest by applying the chain rule as long as you know what the derivative of $e^X$ is.

By you can also write it out via index notation:
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}  [\text{tr} Ae^X ]
  =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \left[\sum_{l} (Ae^X)_{ll}\right]
  =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \left[\sum_{lk} A_{lk}(e^X)_{kl}\right]
  =
  \sum_{lk} A_{lk} \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \left[(e^X)_{kl}\right].
$$
This comes down to the same: As long as you know what the derivative of $e^X$ is, you can compute the derivative of the original expression.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\rs#1{\op{Unvec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sk#1{\LR{\sum_{k=0}^\infty #1}}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^k}
$Use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in numerous ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
Now we can use a power series expansion of the exponential
to calculate the differential and gradient of your function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A^T:e^{X} \\
 &= A^T:\Sk{\frac{X^k}{k!}} \\
d\phi &= A^T:\Sk{\frac{\c{dX^k}}{k!}} \\
 &= A^T:\Sk{\;\frac{\c{\Sj X^{k-j}\:dX\:X^{j-\o}}}{k!}} \\
 &= \Sk{\Sj \frac{X^{j-\o}\:A\:X^{k-j}}{k!}}^T:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
 &= \Sk{\Sj \frac{X^{k-j}\:A\:X^{j-\o}}{k!}} \\
}$$
where the last line takes advantage of the fact that both of your matrices are symmetric.

### Daleckii-Krein

Since $X$ is symmetric it can be diagonalized which permits the use of the [Daleckii-Krein Theorem](http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2466/1/gendk.pdf)
$$\eqalign{
X &= QBQ^T,\quad B = \Diag{b},\quad Q^TQ=I \\
F &= f(X) \\
dF &= Q\LR{R\odot\LR{Q^TdX\,Q}}Q^T \\
d\phi &= A^T:dF \;=\; Q\LR{R\odot\LR{Q^TA^TQ}}Q^T:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= Q\LR{R\odot\LR{Q^TA^TQ}}Q^T \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product.

All we need is the symmetric $R$ matrix, which lies at the heart of the theorem
$$\eqalign{
R_{ij} &= \begin{cases} 
{\Large\frac{f(b_i)\,-\,f(b_j)}{b_i\,-\,b_j}} \quad{\rm if}\; b_i\ne b_j \\
\\
\qquad f'(b_j) \qquad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$

Comment: The vectorization approach is quite interesting as I have other similar equations. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the vectorization approach won't work because the $M$ matrix is singular. I think it can be salvaged by including a vector from the nullspace of $M$ and enforcing a symmetric constraint on $X$. While attempting that, I recalled the Daleckii-Krein theorem, which seems like an even better approach.

Comment: @PC1 The vectorization approach was removed from the post since it could not be salvaged. Daleckii-Krein seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is indeed the most appropriate approach I believe too.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unpleasant derivative, except in special cases such as when $A$ is a power of $X$, or where you only care about the derivative of your function in direction of $X$.

You can brute-force the derivative using the Zassenhaus formula; another approach, assuming that the eigenvalues of $X$ are distinct, is to take the spectral decomposition $X = VDV^T$ and observe that
$$\operatorname{tr}(A\exp(X)) = \operatorname{tr}(AV\exp(D)V^T) = \exp(D) : V^TAV = \sum_{i} e^{\lambda_i} v_i^T A v_i,$$
where $(\lambda_i, v_i)$ are $X$'s eigenpairs.

Now you can apply standard formulas for the derivative of eigenvectors and eigenvalues with respect to variations $\delta X$ in $X$:

$$d\left[\operatorname{tr}(A\exp(X))\right]\delta X = \sum_i\left[ e^{\lambda_i} (v_i^T\delta X v_i) (v_i^T A v_i) + 2e^{\lambda_i} \sum_{j\neq i} \left( \frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}[v_i^T \delta X v_j] [v_i^T A v_j] \right)\right].$$

Comment: That's what I also see, if $A$ and $X$ commute then the solution is straightforward to express, unfortunately this is not true in general. I can certainly assume that the eigenvalues of $X$ are all distinct, this is certainly a good way to approach the problem. I will check if I can use any structure on the eigenvalue distribution, maybe that expression can be computed approximately without having to consider all the terms.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Matrix calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities) which states that

\begin{align}
\text{Differentials}: \qquad & \text{d}(\operatorname {tr} (\mathbf {X} ))= \displaystyle \operatorname {tr} (\text{d}(\mathbf {X}) ), \\[1em]
\text{Trace of $\mathbf{X}$}: \qquad & \frac {\partial \operatorname {tr} (\mathbf {X} )}{\partial \mathbf {X} }= \mathbf {I}, \\[1em]
\text{Matrix multiply with $\mathbf{X}$}: \qquad & \frac {\partial \operatorname {tr} (\mathbf {AX} )}{\partial \mathbf {X} } = \frac {\partial \operatorname {tr} (\mathbf {XA} )}{\partial \mathbf {X}} \equiv \mathbf {A}, \\[1em]
\text{Trace of exponential}: \qquad & \frac {\partial \operatorname {tr} \left(e^{\mathbf {X} }\right)}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = e^{\mathbf {X}}.
\end{align}

Which gives in your case

\begin{align}
\text{Expression in question}: \qquad & \frac {\partial \operatorname {tr} \left(\mathbf {A} e^{\mathbf {X} }\right)}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = 
 ~... \text{work in progress} ...
\end{align}

Comment: We must have that $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$ for any (compatible) matrices $A$ and $B$. The last expression in your answer is incorrect. The main problem is that $A$ and $X$ do not commute in general.

Comment: In other words, $\exp(X)A\ne\partial_X\mathrm{tr}(A\exp(X))\ne A\exp(X)$ in general.

Comment: You are correct, I will check my answer.

Comment: After working on this for some time, I don't believe that simple matrix identities can be used to solve this problem. It gets very intricate as soon as $[A,X]\ne0$ or the dimension of the square matrices is larger than $1\times1$.

Comment: Yes seems so. It looks quite easy in first place. I think the answers by Lutz Lehmann and user168715 go in the right direction, using some Lie algebra stuff.